# Need datasheet for PU392

Tags: transistors

I have a 5000 pcs. Package of PU392 transistors, but I cannot find a datasheet for the PU392. It is a NPN transistor in a modified TO92 case with cooling from National Semiconductors.
[image]

Goggle and the various datasheet websites do not find this transistor.
How can I find the datasheet for the PU392?

Comment: Where did you get them from?

Comment: May have been some custom marking; you'd need to know who ordered them marked that way.

Comment: Don't buy stuff without a data sheet.